# Android simple OKHTTP not working at all

Tags: android, post, okhttp

Help, I don't know what's going on, but my OKHTTP aplication don't do what I want.
It starts and all, no error and so on, but don't do run() Method at all. Here's the code.

```
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aktualnosci);


    try {
        run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
public void run() throws Exception {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

    Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
    for (int i = 0; i < responseHeaders.size(); i++) {
       Log.d("responseHeaders.name(i)",  "responseHeaders.value(i)");
    }

    System.out.println(response.body().string());
}
```

How can I fix it.

Comment: Have set break points and stepped into the code? Does it hit the catch block? Are you on the main thread?

Comment: You are making the network request on the main thread. This is an illegal operation in android.

Comment: So how should I make network request like this?